# Create a copy of a customized sublime text

Tags: sublime-text-3

I am a TA at University and am thinking about using Sublime text in one of my classes - and having my students use it as well. I have some standard packages/extensions that I believe make Sublime much more usable and would like to pass those along to my students.

Is it possible to basically create a copy of my version of sublime (including extensions/settings I have chosen) and give to my students so they can install and are ready to go?

I have seen this in other applications (pre-configured setting) and am wondering if it is possible to do in Sublime.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sublime is not free software, You will be instructing the students to purchase licenses?  Redistributing the software would also probably violate the license.

Anyway, ignoring all the licensing concerns, consider using the portable version.  The portable version places the install, and all the data files within a single directory.  You can copy or move that directory to other places as needed.

Comment: It is just an idea I'm playing around with. If I was to require students to use Sublime it works fine as an unregistered product, and if they wanted to purchase a license it would be ridiculous cheap compared to other classes textbook prices.

Comment: I'll check out the portable version, thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to distribute your **User** package from the Packages directory. You can open the Packages directory via **Preferences > Browse Packages...**. The **User** directory contains all self defined settings and the installed packages, which is a setting itself. Everybody can just put it into his Packages directory and install Package Control via **Tools > Install Package Control**. Then the packages will automatically install.

This way you can provide a version for each OS and the User folder is usually very small. However you need to ensure, that you have all packages installed via Package Control.